# How to Sort Addresses (School work)?

Tags: java

So I have to sort stuff, using String.split and Bubblesort, the problem is: I WAS NEVER TOLD HOW TO USE String.split.
Also, we need to get it out of a file.

```
public class A2017125SortingThings {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int x;
    int y;
    int count;
    String Name [];
    String Lastname [];
    String Zip [];
    String State[];
    String City[];

    File xyz = new File ("A20171204AddressSortList.dat");
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(xyz);

   count = infile.nextInt();
   Name = new String [count+1];
   Lastname = new String [count+1];
   Zip = new String [count+1];
   State = new String [count+1];
   City = new String [count+1];

    String.split("newdata");
    Name = newdata [0];
    Lastname = newdata [1];
    Zip = newdata [2];
    State = newdata [3];
    City = newdata [4];
```

That's an example my teacher gave us, I am trying to use it (I edited and added what I needed to edit, which is everything up to String.split) but of course it doesn't work, "non-static method split(java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from static context" is the error and if I can't figure that out how can I start with the bubblesort?

Comment: umm, advice: *Don't tell anyone on SO that the question is your home work*

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Why? As long as the OP shows some effort and asks a specific question, the post is ok. Usually we complain because most times homework is just dumped here and the OP expects us to do all the work, it has really nothing to do with it being homework at all.

Comment: @Aniket even if you don't say it, it is usually pretty obvious. You'll get a much better response by being upfront, rather than trying to pass it off as something else.

Comment: "I WAS NEVER TOLD HOW TO USE String.split" fortunately, it is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), and your preferred search engine will turn up numerous examples of how to use it. Knowing what to look for is, ooh, 90% of the problem, and you clearly know what to look for.

Comment: @AndyTurner I tried to look but all I found where examples of terms I didn't understood (With names and commands I have never seen, I didn't knew how they related or changed the String.split or made it work, also, we are not supposed to use terms the teacher didn't show us), I didn't knew it was documented, for that, I thank you, knowing more will help me !.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting tells you that String's `split` function, which you're using, is non-static. A static method is called on the class, a good example is `Math.random()`. A non-static method is called on an object, for example, if you had a String, you could call `split` on it.

```
String str = "this_is_a_bunch_of_words_separated_by_underscores";
String[] words = str.split("_");
```

If you read the [String.split documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), you can see that what this method does is take in a regular expression as a parameter, (here I just used the "_" character, in order to match the underscores) and returns an Array of Strings, separated by the given expression ("_"). So `String[] words` would be an array containing each word, like this `[this, is, a, bunch, of, words, separated, by, underscores]`

Comment: I am sorry, I understand what you mean but I don't understand what I should change, I mean I understand I need to call it non-static, this is an example of what I need to sort and how "79932, Tx, El paso, Loy lane,950,Antigua,Luis,(915)434-300" I did this in the code String str = 
        String [] Words = str.split(","); but what do I do to set the parameters? (Also I get ".class expected" I am sorry, for asking so much, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use `Collections.sort(your array)`

Comment: `Collections.sort()` requires `List<T>` and not array. You may consider responding to: *"non-static method split(java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from static context"*

Comment: The first and last sentences of the question state that a bubble sort must be used.  Clearly, the assignment expects students to write their own sorting code.

Comment: @Aniket there is also `Arrays.sort`.

Comment: @AndyTurner `Arrays.sort()` and `Collections.sort()` are different methods

Comment: @AniketSahrawat yes, `Arrays.sort` requires an array and not `List<T>`. What would be the point in two methods which do the same thing?